# How to clear up all the text on my display

Tags: python, text, pygame, display

I’m the first time to ask on stack overflow! I’m a 12-year-old boy who living in Hong Kong, so if my English was wrong, please tell me and please don’t keep in mind. Apart from that, I’m a newer of Python. I don’t know that the meaning of the code. Can everyone making a `#` to tell me the meaning? Thank you!!

I am doing a project that use Python. Also, for the display, I use Pygame too. But there have some problem with the displays. 
Here is my testing code:

```
# install pygame
import pygame
from pygame import *
pygame.init()

# play music
mixer.init()
mixer.music.load("game_music.mp3")
mixer.music.play()

# colour
red = (255, 0, 0)
green = (0, 255, 0)
blue = (0, 0, 255)
grass_green = (112, 173, 71)
white = (255, 255, 255)
black = (0, 0, 0)

# screen settings
window = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 600))
window.fill(grass_green)
pygame.display.set_caption("What's Your Number?")

# fonts settings
default_font = pygame.font.get_default_font()
font_a = pygame.font.Font(default_font, 57)
font_b = pygame.font.Font(default_font, 30)
font_c = pygame.font.Font(default_font, 18)

# text
title = font_a.render("What's Your Number?", 1, white)
enter_to_start = font_b.render("Press the Enter to start", 1, white)
random_mode = font_a.render("Random Mode", 1, black)
your_mode = font_a.render("Your Mode", 1, black)
des_random_1 = font_c.render("The PC choose a random number for you to", 1, black)
des_random_2 = font_c.render("guess! Can you guess it correct?", 1, black)
des_your = font_c.render("Pick a number and let you friends to guess!", 1, black)
random_control = font_b.render("Press the up arrow", 1, black)
your_control = font_b.render("Press the down arrow", 1, black)

# image
up_arrow = pygame.image.load("up_arrow_new.png")
down_arrow = pygame.image.load("down_arrow_new.png")


def blit_img(img, x, y):
    window.blit(img, (x, y))


# game
game = False
temp = True
while not game:
    if temp:
        window.blit(title, (10, 150))
        window.blit(enter_to_start, (160, 350))
        pygame.display.flip()
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_KP_ENTER:
                    temp = False
                    window.fill(grass_green)
                    pygame.draw.rect(window, red, [50, 50, 540, 225])
                    pygame.draw.rect(window, blue, [50, 325, 540, 225])
                    window.blit(random_mode, (55, 65))
                    window.blit(des_random_1, (55, 150))
                    window.blit(des_random_2, (55, 200))
                    window.blit(random_control, (55, 240))
                    blit_img(up_arrow, 450, 150)
                    window.blit(your_mode, (55, 335))
                    window.blit(des_your, (55, 425))
                    window.blit(your_control, (55, 515))
                    blit_img(down_arrow, 450, 425)
                    pygame.display.flip()
                    if event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                        if temp == False:
                            temp = True
                            window.fill(grass_green)
                            pygame.display.flip()
                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    game = True
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                game = True
```

I want to make it just like a book or a PowerPoint to have pages. In this code, my problem is that the text which displayed cannot erase and `blit` the new text on it. Can someone help me? Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to remove previous stuff in pygame is to draw the background and everything you want to keep over it. In this case, you want to remove the Hello, so you will have to stop pygame from drawing it, and then draw the background over it

It should look like this:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

#colour settings
white = (255, 255, 255)
black = (0, 0, 0)
red = (255, 0, 0)
green = (0, 255, 0)
blue = (0, 0, 255)

#making a screen(display)
window = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 600))
window.fill(green)

# fonts settings
default_font = pygame.font.get_default_font()
font = pygame.font.Font(default_font, 57)
temp = True

#the things I want to display
while True:
    if temp:
        what_I_say = font.render("Hello", 1, white)
        window.blit(what_I_say, (10, 150))
    pygame.display.flip()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                temp = False
                window.fill(green)
                pygame.draw.rect(window, red, [50, 50, 540, 500])
```

The boolean temp marks whether to draw Hello. On pressing return (my keyboard doesn't have keypad enter), temp is set to false (so it will stop drawing Hello), the window is refilled with green (to cover the previous hello), and then a red rectangle is drawn.

Comment: Thank you!! It solved the problem! Thank you very much!!

Comment: How about make one more clear up? Do I just need to make one more temp variable and do like you?

Answer (score 1):

I'd fill the window every frame and then render and blit the current text. The texts can be stored in a list and the current text can be accessed with an index variable that you increment in the event loop.

```
import pygame


pygame.init()

white = (255, 255, 255)
black = (0, 0, 0)

window = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 600))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()  # A clock to limit the frame rate.
font = pygame.font.Font(None, 57)  # Use the default font.
texts = ['Hello', "what's", 'up?']
text_index = 0

done = False
while not done:
    # Handle events.
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # Allow the user to quit by clicking on the 'X' button.
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key in (pygame.K_KP_ENTER, pygame.K_RETURN):
                # Make sure that we don't get an IndexError.
                if text_index < len(texts)-1:
                    # Increment the index.
                    text_index += 1

    # Insert additional game logic here.

    # Finally draw everything.
    window.fill(white)  # Use fill to clear the window.
    what_I_say = font.render(texts[text_index], True, black)
    window.blit(what_I_say, (10, 150))

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(30)  # Limit the frame rate to 30 FPS.
```

If you really only need to update the window when the user wants to switch to the next page (an event occurs), you could also use [`pygame.event.wait`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.wait) instead of `pygame.event.get`.

Comment: It can't fix it since the code in my question is just a testing code and my real game code is not applicable of your answer. Or do you mind that I give you the real code and help me to fix it?

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Please describe your goals and problems more precisely. If you want, you can add your actual code to the question, but don't just post your complete project and try to [reduce the code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) first.

Comment: My game is to ask people to guess a number, so it will have many settings, but not just text. I don't know how to make controls of list.